# Running "sudo chef-client" does not update with latest version of cookbook

Tags: chef

Here's the situation:

I have a recipe that I've been working on to install monit and install a custom monit configuration. That configuration has changed the past couple of days.

I have a chef server and a chef node. The server has the most up-to-date version the recipe I've mentioned. When I run 'sudo chef-client', it seems to run the usual statements, but when I check on the monit configuration, it's an old version, not the latest.

When I use the web UI for my chef server, I can see that it has the latest version of my recipe.

How can I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 3):

Your node's environment definition may have a cookbook constraint.  Check the environment for something like this:

> cookbook     "monit", "= 1.3.5"

You might have some confusion with the actual cookbook contents that you pushed up to chef.  You can pull down a specific version directly from chef and make sure it has everything you want by doing `knife cookbook download monit`.  It will prompt to select a version and then you can fish through the contents to see if it is what you thought it was.

Answer (score 0):

First debug all version of cookbooks on server and then check which version of cookbook the client is downloading. if it is old, just check if the server has an updated version. if it is also yes, Please go to chef server UI and check for env. you might have setup an enviornment in which cookbooks constraint are specified. Please update the version over there and it will start working again.